# How can i add users with gmail accounts to my live streaming broadcast video using youtube api?

Tags: php, json, youtube-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

Is it possible to add users to the live stream video from api request ??

If yes, how is it done. I have gone through many times in the api docs but could not find a thing on adding the selected users to the video from the api. Help me out guys.

P.S I already know that the users can be added from direct youtube dashboard and the users need to have gmail accounts. Here my question is how to add from the api request not from youtube livestream dashboard.

I dont think i need to upload my code here. However, my code is copy paste given from youtube developers guide. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts

Also, my video is set to scope PRIVATE

Comment: when a user watches a livestream, isn't he added by default to the live stream?

Comment: @Ruchan No.. I forgot to mention it is for my private video. I have set the scope to private. So, in private we need to share in order to watch it.

Comment: in that case have a look at this https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=2783

Comment: I dont think this is possible now..